# How to use "svn add" recursively in Windows console?

Tags: svn, windows-xp

When I run

```
svn st
```

on my working copy I get some "?" entries which are located in subdirectories of working copy root. I want to add all of them to the repository. I try:

```
svn add --force .
```

and

```
svn add --force *
```

but it doesn't work.

**WORKING SOLUTION**:

```
svn add --depth=infinity --force *
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't know if it work in windows, but you could try:

```
svn add --depth=infinity *
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps try:

```
svn status | grep '^\?' | sed -e 's/^? *\(.*\)/\1/;s/ /\\ /g' | xargs svn add
```

Comment: -1: He needs this for Windows, not a Unix/Linux platform where sed and grep don't exist unless he has Cygwin installed, but the question doesn't indicate that.