# Add all unversioned files to SVN, @2x included

Tags: svn, unix, command-line, terminal

I use this to add all unversioned files to SVN:

```
svn status |grep '\?' |awk '{print $2}'| xargs svn add
```

However it doesn't include files with an "@2x" suffix.

How would I modify the line above to include "@2x" files in the SVN add?

Comment: Apache Subversion interprets '@' as a peg revision specifier. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757435/how-to-escape-characters-in-subversion-managed-file-names for further details and please also consider the following SVNBook chapter: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218237/subversion-add-all-unversioned-files-to-subversion-using-one-linux-command

    svn add --force <directory>

Comment: @user1688936 does it really solve the issue with the peg revision specifier?

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2012? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apache Subversion interprets the *"at sign"* (**'@'**) as [a peg revision specifier](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) and it seems to be the cause here. I advise you to check the [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/757435/761095) discussing the case when you have file or folders with **'@'** sign in it's name.

According to the [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/) you can customize your command to append **'@@'** to the end of the path you pipe to `svn add` in order to workaround the issue. E.g. the following answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292498/761095.

> The perceptive reader is probably wondering at this point whether the
>   peg revision syntax causes problems for working copy paths or URLs
>   that actually have at signs in them. After all, how does svn know
>   whether news@11 is the name of a directory in my tree or just a syntax
>   for “revision 11 of news”? Thankfully, while svn will always assume
>   the latter, there is a trivial workaround. **You need only append an at
>   sign to the end of the path, such as news@11@. svn cares only about
>   the last at sign in the argument, and it is not considered illegal to
>   omit a literal peg revision specifier after that at sign. This
>   workaround even applies to paths that end in an at sign—you would use
>   filename@@ to talk about a file named filename@.**