# svn 1.7 error E200009 Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned

Tags: svn

I did a clean checkout of a repository then every day I have an hudson job that runs a script to backup the configuration. Part of the script is to add `*.xml`

```
$ svn add *.xml
svn: warning: W150002: '/data/hudson/config.xml' is already under version control
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

The warning is fine because some of the xml files are already under version control but I don't understand why I get the `E200009` error. If there is nothing to add, there should be no error.

Comment: In my case `svn co {repo_url}` was needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like the correct behaviour for SVN 1.7. An alternative is to add only unversioned files:

```
svn st *.xml | grep ? | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | xargs svn add
```

However it's possible you have nothing to add, so you will get

```
svn: E205001: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205001: Not enough arguments provided
```

Related question: [Add all unversioned files to Subversion using one Linux command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218237/subversion-add-all-unversioned-files-to-subversion-using-one-linux-command)

Comment: I am trying to add a file to an inner sub-directory. I tried the below, `svn st *.xml | grep ? | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | xargs svn add filename.tpl` I am facing `svn: warning: W155010: '/var/www/html/example/filename.tpl' not found` with couple of `svn: E200009` as in question.

Answer (score 11):

`svn add something --force` will solve the error E200009. In your case, `svn add *.xml --force` will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Once, I met this error info, because I add a directory in a SVN directory. The directory which I added is copied from another SVN director, and it had a `.svn` directory, so I met the error info.
Remove the `.svn` directory (`rm -rf .svn`) and it will work after.

This is the same case I met. Hope it help some other people.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with netbeans where the GUI has "Commit" which is adding and committing as a single step. The solution was to use the command line, and call "svn commit -m "message", i.e. for some read the "add" step was already done when a file was copied.

Answer (score -1):

Like Sydney's answer, I have another one-line command:

`svn st | grep ^? | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add`