# svn 1.7 fresh checkout can't commit change

Tags: svn, commit, svn-checkout

I have an SVN subtree that has been working fine for 2+ years. I now encountered that I cannot commit some files.

I did a fresh checkout and ensured no other program accesses the folder.

When I do:

```
svn ci -m"fix filter" symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/MembershipForm.class.php 
svn: E200009: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200009:     '/home/jochen/projects/nzgbctest/symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/MembershipForm.class.php' is not under version control
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
svn status symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/MembershipForm.class.php
```

shows nothing

```
svn add symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/MembershipForm.class.php
```

or

```
svn add --force symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/MembershipForm.class.php
```

show

```
svn: warning: W155010: '/home/jochen/projects/nzgbc/symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/MembershipForm.class.php' not found
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets don't exist
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

strangely:

```
ls -la symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/MembershipForm.class.php
```

and

```
cd symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/
ls -la MembershipForm.class.php
```

show

```
ls: cannot access MembershipForm.class.php: No such file or directory
```

but

```
cd symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/
ls -la
```

contains

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jochen jochen 7671 Jun 28 13:08 MembershipFormFilter.class.php
```

Is my disk broken? My IDE finds the file and I can edit it, but

```
nano symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/MembershipForm.class.php
```

shows an empty file!

apache can read the file as well, as changes have an effect.

The same repository is also checked out on the live site and works fine there.

Comment: Hope this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620547/svn-1-7-error-e200009-could-not-add-all-targets-because-some-targets-are-already

Answer (score 2):

Buying a new harddisk and imaging the data across has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

svn add first?

```
svn add symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/MembershipForm.class.php
svn ci -m "fix filter" symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/MembershipForm.class.php
```

Comment: are there any symbolic links between the original folder and the target file? are there any `svn:externals` in play?

Comment: only symfony/lib/vendor is an external

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue on the Apache Subversion Issues list: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4193

Answer (score 0):

make sure you added correct folder or file.  To fix the error of E200009, you can just `svn add {file or folder} --force`. And you need add first, then commit